# LEAD and LAG function by omitting 0

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOmeE.png)
I want to omit 0 while applying LEAD and LAG function.
For highlighted column, prev should be 116.69635888009 and next should be 108.324381114468
I am using the query below:

```sql
select 
   snapshot_date,
   assetname,
   prev,
   monthly_avg_kw,
   next,
   (prev+next)/2 as avg
FROM 
(select 
    snapshot_date,
    assetname,
    monthly_avg_kw,
    LAG(monthly_avg_kw) OVER(PARTITION BY assetname ORDER BY snapshot_date ASC) as prev,
    LEAD(monthly_avg_kw) OVER(PARTITION BY assetname ORDER BY 
    snapshot_date ASC) as next
 from 'TABLE')
where assetname = 'MI6.UPS-2A-2'
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Can you add these filters in where clause : "prev <> 0 and monthly_avg_kw <> 0 and NEXT <> 0"

Comment: It is not taking the record with 0 values of prev or monthly_avg_kw or next.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL, I was able to create this example, which produces the desired behavior.

Adding `(b>0)` to the order by causes the previous value to be based only on column where b>0. This will produce NULL when the value of b is 0. In that case we use COALESCE to find the previous value just on the order by a.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  a integer,
  b INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
   (1,1),
   (2,2),
   (3,0),
   (4,4),
   (5,5),
   (6,6);

SELECT 
   a,b, 
   COALESCE(lag(b) over (order by (b>0),a),lag(b) over (order by a)) as BB
FROM test
ORDER BY a;
```

output:

| a | b | BB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 5 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/8jloeLsN)